# Передача текстовой строки из объекта класса View в TextView активности

Tags: java, android

Хочу передать текстовую строку из объекта класса View в TextView. Оба объекта находятся на лайоте активности. Обращение по ID не работает, приложение крашится.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout ml = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLay);
        Qwerty Q = new Qwerty(MainActivity.this, null);
        ml.addView(Q);
    }
}
```

Qwerty.java:

```
public class Qwerty extends View {

    private int size;
    private String s;

    public Qwerty(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Qwerty(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public Qwerty(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int hightMeasureSpec){
        int W = measure(widthMeasureSpec); //определяем ширину
        int H = measure(hightMeasureSpec); //определяем высоту
        size = Math.min(W, H);
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
        System.out.println("Размер = " + size);
        s = "Размер =  " + size;//Эту строку передать в TextView
    }

    private int measure(int measureSpec){
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) result = 200;
        else result = specSize;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Читал про интенты, но во всех примерах передается из одной активности в другую. Никак догнать не могу как это сделать.

Comment: а код получающий по `id` доступ к элементам используется в коде `Activity`?

Comment: Нет, не используется.

Comment: а откуда вы пытались по `id` получать доступ к элементам?

Comment: Если получать доступ в MainActivity, то Qwerty.java не видит этого элемента, соответственно отсутствует доступ к методу setText.

Comment: вот вы фактически и подошли к решению вашей проблемы: к элементам имеет доступ только класс активности, поэтому она и должна описывать взаимодействие, а Qwerty может просто обращаясь к активности вызывать ее метод который это взаимодействие будет выполнять.

Comment: сейчас более подробно опишу с примером кода

Comment: В этом и вопрос, никак не могу понять, как вызвать метод активности.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно зачем создавать класс Qwerty, если по сути он не делает никакой логики.

Comment: Столкнулся с этим вопросом в рамках другого проекта. А класс Qwerty создан в качестве примера, чтобы не обременять лишними строками кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша активность:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView youTextView; // допустим ваш TextView

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout ml = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLay);

        // получаете контроль над TextView
        youTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youTextView)

        Qwerty Q = new Qwerty(MainActivity.this, null);
        ml.addView(Q);
    }

    // метод установки текста в TextView
    public void setText(String text){
        youTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

В ваш Qwerty просто добавить метод (ну и вызвать для работы):

```
public void transferText(){
        ((MainActivity)getContext()).setText(s)
}
```

Метод костыльный, но объясняющий суть вопроса: как из вне активности управлять ее элементами.

Comment: Что за `getActivity()` - это ж не фрагмент.

Comment: Класс View не знает getActivity поэтому сделал так: private Fragment objFragment и далее создаю конструктор objFragment = new Fragment(). Но при вызове метода transferText приложение вылетает.

Comment: @mrdryn, у пустого фрагмента нет Вашей `MainActivity`, зато классу `Qwerty` Вы передаёте её в качестве контекста - этим можно и воспользоваться (`getContext()` вместо `getActivity()` в коде из ответа, к примеру).

Comment: Да, вы правы насчет фрагмента, сглупил. Через getContext() всё заработало.

Comment: поправил ответ - а ведь изначально все правильно написал, а потом уже чего-то поменял на `getActivity()`